# UInt32 and UInt64 types cannot be inferred from the usage when used along with Int32 type in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-construction, type-conversion

Initially I faced this issue when I was testing my code with UnitTest framework using Assert.AreEqual methods. I noticed that for UInt32 and UInt64 types different overload of AreEqual was selected (AreEqual(object, object) instead of AreEqual<T>(T, T)). I did some research and got the following simple code:

```
public struct MyInteger
{
    public SByte SByte { get; set; }
    public Byte Byte { get; set; }
    public UInt16 UInt16 { get; set; }
    public UInt32 UInt32 { get; set; }
    public UInt64 UInt64 { get; set; }
    public Int16 Int16 { get; set; }
    public Int32 Int32 { get; set; }
    public Int64 Int64 { get; set; }
}

public class MyGenericClass
{
    public static void DoNothing<T>(T expected, T actual)
    {
    }
}

public class IntegerTest
{
    public void TestIntegers()
    {
        var integer = new MyInteger
        {
            SByte = 42,
            Byte = 42,
            Int16 = 42,
            Int32 = 42,
            Int64 = 42,
            UInt16 = 42,
            UInt32 = 42,
            UInt64 = 42
        };
        MyGenericClass.DoNothing(42, integer.SByte); // T is Int32
        MyGenericClass.DoNothing(42, integer.Byte); // T is Int32
        MyGenericClass.DoNothing(42, integer.Int16); // T is Int32
        MyGenericClass.DoNothing(42, integer.Int32); // T is Int32
        MyGenericClass.DoNothing(42, integer.Int64); // T is Int64
        MyGenericClass.DoNothing(42, integer.UInt16); // T is Int32
        MyGenericClass.DoNothing(42, integer.UInt32); // Error
        MyGenericClass.DoNothing(42, integer.UInt64); // Error
        MyGenericClass.DoNothing((UInt32)42, integer.UInt32); // T is UInt32
        MyGenericClass.DoNothing((UInt64)42, integer.UInt64); // T is UInt64
    }
}
```

The Error message I get is "The type arguments for method 'MyGenericClass.DoNothing<T>(T, T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.". The workaround is relatively easy (use explicit cast), so I just want to know, what is so special about UInt32 and UInt64, what other types don't have (or have), and why UInt16 is not behaving the same way?
P.S. Oh, I almost forgot - I've found this table of type [conversions](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Semantics/Conversions/ConversionEasyOut.cs#35), but first of all - it is for new "Roslyn" compiler, and second of all - I don't see the answer there anyway, maybe someone will point it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `T` is shared for both arguments to `DoNothing`, the compiler can only use it if there is a common base class or implicit operator to convert to a common class for both inputs.

The two errors come because there is no implicit conversion for `UInt32` or `UInt64` to/from `Int32` (your `42` literal).

The reason there is no implicit conversion is because there can an information loss between the two. All the other conversions share a common range of values. For example, `UInt16` has a range of 0 to 65535, which is within the range of a normal `int`. Same goes for `Byte` which can be represented as `0-7`. C# considers these kinds of conversions "safe" and so can be performed implicitly. But `UInt32` can go from 0 to 4,294,967,295 which is twice as high as a normal `int` can possibly go. C# considers these kinds of conversions not safe and requires you to perform an `explicit` cast conversion. The semantics of which denote that you *expect* that this conversion might fail under certain circumstances (values being outside a compatible range).

```
DoNothing(42, integer.SByte); // Converts SByte to Int32
DoNothing(42, integer.Byte); // Converts Byte to Int32
DoNothing(42, integer.Int16); // Converts Int16 to Int32
DoNothing(42, integer.Int32); // Already the same
DoNothing(42, integer.Int64); // Converts Int32 to Int64
DoNothing(42, integer.UInt16); // Converts UInt16 to Int32
DoNothing(42, integer.UInt32); // Error - no implicit conversion
DoNothing(42, integer.UInt64); // Error - no implicit conversion
DoNothing((UInt32)42, integer.UInt32); // Explicitly converted to UInt32
DoNothing((UInt64)42, integer.UInt64); // Explicitly converted to UInt64
```

The explicit conversion worked because you purposely chose a number that was within the shared range of `int` and `Int32` and `Int64`. If you change it to *negative* 42, it wouldn't work. (rather, it *could* if you ran it in an `unchecked` context and let the number overflow/wraparound.)

Comment: So, simply put, the problem is because there is no conversion between Int32 and UInt32(or UInt64), and that is because potentially there can be an overflow to Int32?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin: Yup, pretty much. Overflow values exists both _to_ and _from_ Int32 and UInt32/UInt64. EDIT: Because of that, the C# designers decided that you should explicitly cast; that makes sure developers recognize that it can fail. Where defined, the implicit conversions will _never_ fail for these built-in numeric types.

Comment: It seems very logical and obvious now, when I know the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When you just provide a literal, say `42` it always means an `Int32` in c#. To answer your question

> Why `integer.UInt32` cannot be inferred?

because `integer.UInt32` is of type `UInt32` where as `42` is of type `Int32` so compiler can't make assumptions about what you meant, hence it produces error.

You need to use `U` suffix which makes the compiler to infer it correctly as `UInt32`

```
MyGenericClass.DoNothing(42U, integer.UInt32);//No error
```

> Why `integer.UInt64` cannot be inferred?

refer above answer, it is same expect you need to use `UL` suffix :)

> Why `integer.UInt16` **can** be inferred?

You'll see that `integer.UInt16` is actually inferred as `Int32` and not `UInt16` because any `UInt16` value can be implicitly converted to `Int32` because its range fits the `Int32` which is `0 - 65535`, and also 42 is a `Int32` so compiler is happy to infer it as `Int32` and not `UInt16`.

Comment: I like your explanation too, but Chris Sinclair ansewred first, sorry :) I'll upvote your answer for the syntax sugar with "U" and "UL", thanks!